# Quickly check if an item is sold out (ASP.NET Core, EF, MySql)

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, load-testing

I'm currently building an app for selling tickets which needs to work under load (20+ purchases per second). Before each purchase I need to check if the event has sold out. I've considered and tried the methods below with limited success:

---

**1. SQL Count on the Tickets table**

```
int sold_tickets = await _dbContext.Tickets
    .Where(a => a.Booking.AccessType.Id == at.Id && a.Status != TicketStatus.Refunded)
    .CountAsync();
```

This maintains concurrency well but does not scale. The query results in a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ...` query which examines every row in the table and takes too long to execute. It is called around five times per user as they go through the booking process.

---

**2. Summary table**

```
public void AddTicket(Ticket t, AccessType at)
{
    using var transaction = _dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();
    try
    {
        //Add 1 to summary table count
        _dbContext.AccessTypeStocks.First(a => a.AccessType == at).ActiveTickets += 1;
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        //Add ticket
        _dbContext.Tickets.Add(t);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch { ...  }
}
```

I created a summary table which is incremented when a ticket is added and decreased when a ticket is removed or refunded. This all takes place in code. I wrapped it in a transaction in an attempt to maintain concurrency. This works fine under low load but after a two-minute load test the summary table is too small by 10%, however the app runs much faster in this scenario. Why am I losing concurrency?

---

**3. Some other changes to SQL**

Would it be better to add a SQL trigger that fires on changes to the tickets table, or could I add another index to the tickets table containing the AccessTypeId, hence avoiding the `LEFT JOIN`?

---

Tables below:

```
CREATE TABLE `tickets` (
`Id` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
`BookingId` VARBINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PrincipalTicket` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`Forename` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`Surname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`Status` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`GuestUserId` VARCHAR(767) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`ClaimedOn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`FriendlyID` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`IDPhotoId` VARBINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Tickets_BookingId` (`BookingId`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Tickets_GuestUserId` (`GuestUserId`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Tickets_IDPhotoId` (`IDPhotoId`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Tickets_AspNetUsers_GuestUserId` FOREIGN KEY (`GuestUserId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`aspnetusers` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Tickets_Bookings_BookingId` FOREIGN KEY (`BookingId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`bookings` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Tickets_UserImages_IDPhotoId` FOREIGN KEY (`IDPhotoId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`userimages` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)


CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
`Id` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
`StartedOn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`Notes` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`IPAddress` TEXT(65535) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`AccessTypeId` VARBINARY(16) NOT NULL,
`AccessListItemId` VARBINARY(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`SignupAttributes` TEXT(65535) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`BallId` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`UserId` VARCHAR(767) NOT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`Refunded` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`AccessToken` TEXT(65535) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
`BallotSuccessful` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
`Confirmed` BIT(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Bookings_AccessListItemId` (`AccessListItemId`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Bookings_AccessTypeId` (`AccessTypeId`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Bookings_BallId` (`BallId`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `IX_Bookings_UserId` (`UserId`) USING BTREE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Bookings_AccessListItems_AccessListItemId` FOREIGN KEY (`AccessListItemId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`accesslistitems` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Bookings_AccessTypes_AccessTypeId` FOREIGN KEY (`AccessTypeId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`accesstypes` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Bookings_AspNetUsers_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`aspnetusers` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_Bookings_Balls_BallId` FOREIGN KEY (`BallId`) REFERENCES `oxexlocal1`.`balls` (`Id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

The count query undergoes a `LEFT JOIN` first with `bookings` and then with `accesstypes`.

This is my first question on StackOverflow - sorry if I've gone about asking the wrong way! If there's a better way to approach this I would love to hear it!

The app is running on a load-balanced AWS architecture for ASP.NET Core MVC, with MySql RDS database.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your relevant table structure including indexes? I would expect a simple count query on a properly indexed set of tables to perform well enough in most scenarios, so adding some indexes would probably resolve the issue of the first query running too slowly.

Comment: @GarethD I've just updated with an image of the table for with indexes - could this be what's slowing everything down? The query is taking ~300ms per call.

Comment: " image of the table for with indexes" ?? Why not post the text output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ....`, see, for more details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: @Luuk My apologies. I've posted the create table script as you suggested. Any ideas?

Comment: Please read: [How to handle a question that asks many things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267058/how-to-handle-a-question-that-asks-many-things)   and [More than one question per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275908/more-than-one-question-per-post)

Comment: about 1) : Create `EXPLAIN PLAN` for this query, and see if correct indexes are being used. Also redefine your booking process, because doing this query five times is a waste.

Comment: You might benefit from a single index on booking on both `Refunded` and `AccessTypeId`, but it would depend on your data distribution as to how much you would benefit. The issue you would have is that although you can use the index on AccessTypeId you still need to do a bookmark lookup back to the main data to find out if that booking has been refunded. By having an index on both columns you'd remove this bookmark lookup which is likely the most expensive operation in your query - e,g, `CREATE INDEX IX_Booking_Refunded_AccessTypeId ON Booking (Refunded, AccessTypeId)`

Comment: Aside from that, I'd be quite cautious about using VARBINARY as a primary key as it makes  I makes a poor clustering key, and will lead to fragmentation and page splits. A good clustering key should be [Narrow, Unique, static, and ever increasing](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/effective-clustered-indexes/). If it is not too late, I'd be inclined to use a surrogate auto increment integer column as a primary key, and if you need a varbinary identifier for each row, store it in a separate column with a further unique index.